# Date picker theme change

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, dark-theme

I am finding this hard to change the Date picker year in dark theme as it is not visible how to fix this.. Change the color of the year and arrow buttons for dark theme.

This is my code for date picker theme

```
 datePickerTheme: DatePickerThemeData(
      weekdayStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      headerForegroundColor: Colors.white,
      dayForegroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.white),
      todayForegroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.white),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff31343b),
      elevation: .5,
      yearForegroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.white),
    ),
```

[image]

Need to change the Date picker color in dark theme in flutter.

Comment: Can you share your current code for showing the datepicker?

Comment: added the date picker code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it might be controlled by the `onSurface` property of the theme's color scheme. If you don't want to change the `onSurface` for the entire application you could give the `showDatePicker` this builder instead:

```
builder: (context, child) {
  return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          colorScheme: Theme.of(context)
              .colorScheme
              .copyWith(onSurface: Colors.red)), //change to your desired color
      child: child!);
},
```

I'm not sure if this totally fixes it but you can try this.

Comment: Thanks it works we need to add the onSurface property in dark theme in Theme data class